# Bind mount the Docker socket into Alpine chroot?

Tags: docker, chroot, bind-mount

I configured an OpenWrt OS on my FriendlyElec NanoPi R6s but decided to add an Alpine chroot to run other stuff in that OpenWrt doesn't have and to isolate it a little bit away; it even lives on it's own MicroSD - a small environment I can destroy to my hearts contend.

Whilst I figured out how to bind-mound certain folders - like my NAS drive - I have not figured out how to get the Docker socket to show up in the chroot.

The other socket I got this working with was `tailscaled`. Sure, I get warnings about incompatible clients, but it's enough to send a ping or grab an IP - so all good.

I did that, as you would expect, with `mount --bind /var/run/tailscaled /chroot/alpine/run/tailscaled` (`var/run/` is a symlink to `/run`, which wouldn't resolve where I want it to in this situation.)

But how do I mount `/var/run/docker.sock` so I can do Docker commands in my chroot?

Thank you very much!

Comment: It should be an almost identical command (you need to expose the docker socket at `/var/run` in the chroot environment).